# Where to place .erl & .hrl files in phoenix project?

Tags: soap, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have phoenix project and am going to use soap request. for that purpose I've generated stubs from wsdl as described [here](https://medium.com/@larryweya/soap-in-elixir-with-soap-64400c585f69#.9uqcwrb9f).
The question is where to put auto-generated .erl and .hrl client modules within phoenix project?

Comment: I believe putting them in `/src` should compile and load them automatically. Can you try that?

Comment: @Dogbert that is correct, you should make that an answer.

Comment: @Dogbert, I mean project created by mix phoenix.new which doesn't have /src or /include folder because it is project for Phoenix framework

Comment: @Natallia Just create those folders? A Phoenix project is just like any other Mix project.

Comment: Thanks @Dogbert. I am trying to use this code in *.ex file it it is not compiling:`salesforce_client:describeMetadata(
        #'P0:describeMetadata'{
            asOfVersion = 3.1415927},
    _Soap_headers = [],
    _Soap_options = [{url,"https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/37.0"}]).`

Answer (score 1):

`erl` files should go in any directory present in the `erlc_paths` config, and `hrl` in the one in specified by `erlc_include_path` config. [The default value of `erlc_paths` is `["src"]` and of `erlc_include_path` is `"include"`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/c16f54c6adc147a4bc84922097852b2062eedd96/lib/mix/lib/mix/project.ex#L552-L553), so you can simply place the `.erl` file(s) in `/src` and `.hrl` file(s) in `/include` and they will be compiled by `mix` and available in your Elixir code.